# Char n got missing while trying to print in loop shell

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I am trying loop over an array that contains urls
so, I have executed these commands in sequence on terminal for get things tested before putting them in actual code.

```
keyUrlPath="/config/a/b/url"
keyIds="/config/a/b/Keys"
KeyArray=("$keyUrlPath" "$keyIds")
for key in "${sdcKeyArray[@]}"; do echo $key; done
```

Output

```
/co fig/a/b/url
/co fig/a/b/Keys
```

Expected output:

```
/config/a/b/url
/config/a/b/Keys
```

No idea why 'n' is getting missed while printing

Comment: Why using ```"${sdcKeyArray[@]}"```? ins't ```"${KeyArray[@]}"``` enough? It prints the desired result for me.

Comment: Have you reset `$IFS`? Did you do `IFS="\n"` or `IFS='\n'`? Use `IFS=$'\n'` to set IFS to a newline.

Comment: @VineyDhiman : You did not show in your code how you are initializing `sdcKeyArray`. If it is really an array, the loop looks good. Please post a complete example, which we can copy to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @VineyDhiman : Also - for the safe side - post the  name of the shell (and version) you are using. You are tagging your question by _shell_ only, which means POSIX shell, but POSIX shell don't have arrays, so you must be using something different.

Comment: For more details, see [3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the manual.